# Netlogo: How using the route variable to actually move along the path

Tags: routes, netlogo

I use two types of turtles, cars and houses. both are randomly positioned.
My goal is to get a route for each car starting from a combined route vector, and have each car move and visit every home that has been assigned to it.
First i create a route for each car from the combined route vector.
I present my code below.
But now, im trying make car follow respective route...

```
globals [ route-vector ]
breed [carr car]
breed [hous housess]
carr-own [ route ]

to setup
clear-all
create-carros
create-casas
make-routes
end

to create-carros
create-carr cars [ set color green ]
ask carr  [
set shape "car"
set size 1.5
setxy random-xcor random-ycor
 ]
end

to create-casas
create-hous house [ set color red ]
ask hous  [
set shape "house"
set size 1.5
setxy random-xcor random-ycor
]
end


to make-routes
set route-vector [ 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 0 1 ] ;5 10 15 20 25
let houses sublist route-vector 0 (length route-vector / 2 )
let carlist sublist route-vector (length route-vector / 2 ) (length route-
vector)
ask carr [ set route [] ]
(foreach carlist houses
 [ [the-car the-house] ->
  ask carr with [who = the-car] [ set route lput the-house route ]
 ]
  )
 end

 to go
  ask carr  [
    ;; if at target, choose a new random target
    ;        if distance route = 0
     ;          [ set route one-of route-vector
     ;            face route ]
    ;        ;; move towards target.  once the distance is less than 1,
     ;        ;; use move-to to land exactly on the target.
    ;        ifelse distance route < 1

    ;let mylist [1 2 3]
     ;foreach route
     face route
     fd 1
;print map last filter first route
    ;    face housess 3
     ;    fd 1

     ;    move-to one-of route
     ;    fd 1

      ]
     ; move-to housess 3
       ;fd 1

      ;tick
      end
```

I want use the route variable to actually move along the path.
but I do not know how to inform each car of their respective route and cause them to move to their homes.

I tried to use the go button with only one car

do: 
     ask car 1
      [
       face route
       fd 1
     but always get the error ("FACE expected input to be an agent but got the 
     list [4 7] instead.")
     ]
     end

in this case I wanted to cause car 1 to move first to house 4 and second to house 7, then back to its original position ...
I've tried several ways, but I can not find a solution. I tried to do it separately, I chose the first item from the "route" list for each car but I still could not ..

If someone can help me, I really appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `who` numbers to index turtles can cause problems- in this case, you'll run into an issue where you can't really dynamically update the list, because `hous` and `carr` numbers are based solely on the order of their creation. It's far better to store the turtles directly in a list, if possible. Check out this example using a modified version of your setup:

```
globals [ route-vector ]
breed [carr car]
breed [hous housess]
breed [spawns spawn]
carr-own [ route route-counter spawn-target target]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-carros
  create-casas
  make-routes
  reset-ticks
end

to create-carros
  create-carr 3 [ set color green ]
  ask carr  [
    set size 1.5
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor

    ; set up a 'route-counter' to act as an index for a car's route
    set route-counter 0
    set target nobody
    set route []    
    pd
  ]

  ; hatch a 'spawn-target' turtle that can be used to return
  ; the carr back to their starting position
  ask carr [    
    hatch 1 [
      set breed spawns
      ht
    ]
    set spawn-target one-of other turtles-here with [ 
      xcor = [xcor] of myself
    ]
  ]
end

to create-casas
  create-hous 5 [ set color red ]
  ask hous  [
    set shape "house"
    set size 1.5
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
end
```

Now, instead of relying on `who` numbers to index the houses, use a list of the houses directly in your `carr` routes:

```
to make-routes
  ; Just use the car-order 
  let car-order [ 0 1 2 0 1 ] 

  ; Create a list of hous directly by sorting them
  let houses sort hous

  ; Your same foreach procedure, but in this case the carr
  ; are storing the house in the list directly to avoid
  ; indexing problems
  ask carr [  ]
  (foreach car-order houses
    [ [the-car the-house] ->
      ask carr with [who = the-car] [ set route lput the-house route ]
    ]
  )
end
```

Then, the `carr` can just iterate over their route to select a new target based on the index value of `route-counter` (with a small break for their `spawn-target`).

```
to go 
  ask carr [

    ; If a car has no target, set the target to the
    ; item indexed by 'route-counter'
    if target = nobody [
      set target item route-counter route
    ]

    ; Movement chunk
    face target
    ifelse distance target > 1 [
      fd 1
    ] [ 
      move-to target

      ; Only advance the route counter if the current target
      ; was not the original spawn point
      if target != spawn-target [
        set route-counter route-counter + 1
      ]
      set target nobody

    ]

    ; If the route counter would index outside of the 
    ; list boundaries, reset it to 0
    if route-counter > length route - 1 [
      set route-counter 0
      set target spawn-target
    ]
  ]  

  tick  
end
```

This is still not super programmatic, as you are relying on your car-order being the same length as the count of your houses, but I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do so maybe it will work.

**EDIT**

As per [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47730424/netlogo-how-using-the-route-variable-to-actually-move-along-the-path/47735178?noredirect=1#comment82473779_47735178)- if you **must** use the `who` number, you can still use the "spawn target" example to have the turtles return to their starting position- just have it happen after the `carr` and `hous` have been spawned. Again, this is definitely not ideal as your model can 'break' if you're not careful with spawn order, number of `carr` / `house`, etc.

So, basic `setup` and `create-casas` procedures as above, with this as your new `create-carros` procedure:

```
to create-carros
  create-carr 3 [ set color green ]
  ask carr  [
    set size 1.5
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor

    ; set up a 'route-counter' to act as an index for a car's route
    set route-counter 0
    set target nobody
    set route []
    pd
  ]
end
```

Now, your `make-routes` can contain the `spawn` target turtles (this example has the out-of-order houses from your comment):

```
to make-routes
  set route-vector [4 7 6 3 5 0 1 2 0 1]
  let houses sublist route-vector 0 (length route-vector / 2 )
  let carlist sublist route-vector (length route-vector / 2 ) (length route-vector)

  (foreach carlist houses
    [ [the-car the-house] ->
      ask car the-car [ 
        set route lput ( housess the-house ) route 
      ]
    ]
  )

  ; hatch a 'spawn-target' turtle that can be used to return
  ; the carr back to their starting position
  ask carr [
    hatch 1 [
      set breed spawns
      ht
    ]
    set spawn-target one-of other turtles-here with [
      xcor = [xcor] of myself
    ]
  ]
end
```

Then, the `go` procedure from above should work without any change.

**EDIT 2**

A simple way to have your carr stop is to set a logical flag so that only carr that meet a certain criteria will move. Consider this modified `car-own` and `create-carros` setup:

```
carr-own [ route route-counter spawn-target target route-complete? ]

to create-carros
  create-carr 3 [ set color green ]
  ask carr  [
    set size 1.5
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor

    ; set up a 'route-counter' to act as an index for a car's route
    set route-counter 0
    set target nobody
    set route []
    set route-complete? false
    pd
  ]
end
```

Here, we now have a boolean (logical) variable called `route-complete?`, which is set to `false` for all new carr. Now, you can add a line into the `go` procedure that says "only cars that have `route-complete?` set to false, do these actions."

```
to go
  ; ask carr with route-complete set to false
  ask carr with [ not route-complete? ] [

    ; If a car has no target, set the target to the
    ; item indexed by 'route-counter'
    if target = nobody [
      set target item route-counter route
    ]

    face target
    ifelse distance target > 1 [
      fd 1
    ] [
      move-to target

      ; Only advance the route counter if the current target
      ; was not the original spawn point. ADDITIONALLY,
      ; if the target is the starting target, set route-complete?
      ; to true for that carr
      ifelse target != spawn-target [
        set route-counter route-counter + 1
      ] [
        set route-complete? true
      ]
      set target nobody
    ]

    ; If the route counter would index outside of the
    ; list boundaries, reset it to 0
    if route-counter > length route - 1 [
      set route-counter 0
      set target spawn-target
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

You'll notice that there's a modified bit in the `move-to` chunk where if the `carr` is moving back to its starting position, it also sets its `route-complete?` to `true, so that the next time`go`is called, that`carr` won't move.

Note that you could change that `route-complete?` to a counter instead of a true/false if you wanted `carr` to run through their route a set number of times.

Comment: Thank you in advance for the great help.

your code works perfectly just with the prayers of the cars.

But I get the route vector outside the netlog, ie I need to use the complete vector route-vector [3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 0 1].
I managed with the code above, separate in route vectors for each car, that is,
car 0 has the route = [3 6]
car 1 has the route = [4 7]
car 2 has the route = [5]
then all cars should return to their starting position.

Comment: what I can not do is make the cars go to their respective houses and return to the starting position ... the problem, as you said, must be to use who numbers to index turtles ... and always gives the error because it has to be a turtle instead of a list

But as that combined route vector needs to be present, I do not know how to do ....

Comment: I understand using just the order of cars and only use sort houses, but the vector may not be sorted because sometimes I can get a route vector type:
[4 7 6 3 5 0 1 2 0 1]
Is there an alternative to being able to use the combined vector, identifying immediately the houses that each car needs to visit through its creation number (who)?
Thank you for your help

Comment: @MarceloAlves - I've made some edits, see if that's what you're after!

Comment: Once again, thank you for the great help. I know I have to be careful about the order of creation of the turtles to get the number of cars and houses. However your response will be very helpful.
Thanks @LukeC

Comment: sorry to bother again @LukeC, but I have been working on this problem and I can not get the turtles to stop in the original position, after visiting all the respective houses..
I've already put it in the code:
        set route-counter 0
        set target spawn-target
        STOP
but they continue to visit the houses.
If I could help, I was grateful.

Comment: @MarceloAlves - `stop` doesn't work quite like that- all it does is exit the current procedure for the turtle that has called it. Importantly, it doesn't affect the turtle at all the next time the procedure containing `stop` is called. See my new edits for a modification that might work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much @LukeC, for the great help and explanation, it was extremely helpful.

Comment: @MarceloAlves Happy to be of service! If this has sorted you out, please click the little check mark at the top of the answer to mark your question as closed.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again @LukeC. There was a new problem in my model and I tried to implement it and I could not, so I thought I'd better contact you, and I hope there's no problem. I really needed your help, because you helped me a lot and came a new problem in this model. 
Can I ask another question or how should I contact you?

Comment: Hi @MarceloAlves - it's no problem. I would definitely ask a new question- if you tag it with NetLogo like you did with this one, it should show up in my feed (plus, it will make it much easier for others to weigh in if I don't know how to help). Cheers!

Comment: Incredible your attention.
I will make a new question, thanks a lot @LukeC.