# make turtles move only on specific patches

Tags: netlogo

I"m fairly new at netlogo so it might seem like a dumb question but here it is :

I have a world with patch with specific attributes that represents parks, buildings, streets (2 types small and large), etc. I want my turtles to move towards a specific point (I managed to do that) using only the patches representing streets but with a tendency to move towards parks and green spaces. 
I was wondering if you could help me to make them use only the patches representing the streets.

here is the way I set up my world and created my turtles :

```
    extensions  
[
  gis   
]


globals    
[
  Batiments
  ChemindeFer
  Cimetiere
  Densite
  Eau
  Ponts
  Routes
  TerrainSports
  Vegetations
]


patches-own 
[
  Cheminferroviaire
  Bati
  pont
  TerraindeSport
  Vege
  cimetary
  water
  road
  densitepop
  Npatchvert

]


breed [ Renards renard]
breed [ Proies proie]


Renards-own
[
  stress
  poids
]


Proies-own
[
  weight
]


to setup          
ca                
  initialiserGIS  
  creerRenard
  creerProie
  move
reset-ticks

end



  to initialiserGIS            


  ; ---------------------- chargement densité ----------------------------

  set Densite gis:load-dataset "desite_ind_g.asc"
  gis:apply-raster Densite densitepop

  let min-Densite gis:minimum-of Densite
  let max-Densite gis:maximum-of Densite
   ask patches
  [
    ifelse densitepop >= 1.5
    [ set pcolor scale-color grey densitepop 1.5 6]
    [ set pcolor white ]
  ]


  ;------------------- chargement des chemin de fer ----------------

  set ChemindeFer gis:load-dataset "chdefer_g.asc"
  gis:apply-raster ChemindeFer Cheminferroviaire
  ask patches with [Cheminferroviaire = 1]
  [set pcolor grey]


   ;--------------------- chargement batiments --------------------

  set Batiments gis:load-dataset "batiment_g.asc"
  gis:apply-raster Batiments Bati
  ask patches with [Bati = 1]
  [set pcolor brown]


   ;--------------------- chargement des ponts --------------------

  set Ponts gis:load-dataset "ponts_g.asc"
  gis:apply-raster Ponts pont
  ask patches with [ pont = 1]
  [set pcolor 87]

  ;--------------------- chargement de l'eau ----------------------

  set Eau gis:load-dataset "eau_g.asc"
  gis:apply-raster Eau water
  ask patches with [ water = 1]
  [set pcolor blue]

  ;--------------------- sports field -----------------

  set TerrainSports gis:load-dataset "terrain_sport_g.asc"
  gis:apply-raster TerrainSports TerraindeSport
  ask patches with [ TerraindeSport = 1]
  [set pcolor green]

  ;--------------------- végétation --------------------

  set Vegetations gis:load-dataset "vegetation_g.asc"
  gis:apply-raster Vegetations Vege
  ask patches with [ vege = 1 ]
  [set pcolor green]

  ;--------------------- cimetary --------------------

  set Cimetiere gis:load-dataset "cimetiere_g.asc"
  gis:apply-raster Cimetiere cimetary
  ask patches with [ cimetary = 1 ]
  [set pcolor green]

  ;---------------------- roads ---------------------------

  set Routes gis:load-dataset "routes_g.asc"
  gis:apply-raster Routes road

  ask patches with
  [ road = 4] [set pcolor 87]
  ask patches with
  [ road = 3] [set pcolor 104]
  ask patches with
  [ road = 0] [set pcolor green]


end




to creerRenard

  create-Renards 10

end 

to move

  ; --- 1st mouvement (towards campus) --- 
  ask renards 
  [ set heading towardsxy 10 101 
  fd 1 ]
end
```

I hope this isn't too much information ... Thank you in advance !

Comment: You have several ideas wrapped together in this question. (1) restricting movement to roads (2) choosing a destination (3) moving toward that destination (4) modifying either destination or movement to prioritise green spaces. I suggest you start with (1) and get that to work first. One way to do this is to create invisible (`hide-turtle`) agents at each road intersection and links to represent the roads. Look at link-walking in the models library in NetLogo, and also at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47730424/netlogo-how-using-the-route-variable-to-actually-move-along-the-path

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is that I have a lot of intersections in my model and I couldn't find a way to create them on the  intersection of the imported raster properly. Is there a way to make the turtles move only on patches with the color blue or value 3 or 4 ? (all of my pixels representing the streets have a value of 3 or 4)

Comment: @tony-bof I that's a nice specific question — please open a new question to ask it, rather than asking it in a comment on an existing question.

Comment: thank you I will do that